# Natural Feature Tracking - augmented reality

Tags: java, android, image-processing, opencv

I want to build an app for Google Android that uses natural feature tracking to create some cool augmented reality. Now what I need is a good library that for Android that does some serious natural feature tracking.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://studierstube.icg.tu-graz.ac.at/handheld_ar/highspeed_nft.php), they have a natural feature tracking runing on mobile phone:

> We developed a new high speed natural feature tracking mechanism that works in real time on any PC as well as any smart phone.

They also provide some libraries.

Comment: I'm really liking everything I'm seeing except the FAQ which tells me "We currently do not provide any of our libraries for download." do you know how I might get this great library.

Answer (score 1):

The software used in Ross's answer looks to have been bought by Qualcomm to develop their own version of AR Dev software. They  have libraries that you can download and use in your Android AR applications.

Look [here](https://ar.qualcomm.com/qdevnet/sdk) for information on that.

I've actually used the software to develop a few applications and it's quite good.
They also have an extension for [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) allowing you to create AR applications a lot more easily.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [windage](http://code.google.com/p/windage/) project might be close to what you need. The project is GPL and not so nasty about distribution. As far as an Android port, that is another matter altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [OpenCV 4 Android](http://opencv.org/downloads.html), a **free** Computer Vision library which has methods for you to make natural feature tracking.
Those methods are [Feature Detectors](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/features2d.html#features2d-2d-features-framework) and using them for video homography.

You can find more details in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11047572/1085483