# Image comparison android

Tags: android, image, image-processing, camera, image-comparison

I have developed an app for image comparison. here i am comparing colors. the reference chart is in the database. the working of my app is like.. Capturing the colors by camera . camera is controlled by camera API not intent. and the captured image is compared with the reference chart. My problem is LIGHT. and I am capturing the image in a white background.. but according to Light change the output is heavily varying. i am using euclidean distance. by Light variation i couldnt getting the correct output. Has anyone have any sugg: to solve the light problem.?? is there any method for normalizing image.?? 
im using android 2.2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045263/opencv-for-android-image-compare

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775342/compare-two-images-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You could use some open Source Image processing libraries hat provides convenient options for image comparisions.

I would suggest you to use OpenCV which has numerous image manipulation functions and you can easily integrate it with android.

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)

May be this could help you in solving the light problems.

Answer (score 0):

IF you facing the light background then i suggest to use  ARBB value of all pixel of both  image ,
you can compare ARGB values of both image , i have recently gone through this task in my one project . here is small code from it .

- that method will give you average ARGB color of image  .
- after having set of average value of both image you just simply compare as two Collection comparison

> ```
> private int[] getAvgARGB(int[] imagePixels ){
>       int [] argbColection  = new int[4];
>       int pixcel=0 , Aavg=0 ,Ravg =0, Gavg=0 ,Bavg=0 ;
>       int pixcelSize  = 0 ; 
>       for(int i = 0 ; i<imagePixels.length; i++){
>           pixcel = imagePixels[i];  //get pixel value (ARGB)
>           int A = (pixcel >> 24) & 0xFF; //Isolate Alpha value...
>               int R = (pixcel >> 16) & 0xFF; //Isolate Red Channel value...
>               int G = (pixcel >> 8) & 0xFF; //Isolate Green Channel value...
>               int B = pixcel & 0xFF; //Isolate Blue Channel value...
>               Aavg += A ;
>               Ravg += R ;
>               Gavg += G ;
>               Bavg += B ;
>         }
>    pixcelSize = imagePixels.length ;  
>
>    argbColection[0] = Aavg/pixcelSize ;
>    argbColection[1] = Ravg/pixcelSize ; 
>    argbColection[2] = Gavg/pixcelSize ;
>    argbColection[3] = Bavg/pixcelSize ;
>
>    return argbColection ;
> }
> ```